# Remove Quotes from Headers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How would I go about removing quotes from the beginning and end of the headers only in a CSV file, python 3?

Just the headers.

```
"WD_Code", "_Supplier_Number", "Date_Of_Snapshot", "Time_Of_Snapshot"
"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"
```

Can this be done while writing the file file.to_csv using pandas?

Answer (score 0):

The headers are just a list that you can access through pandas. You can also reset that list as anything you want. Here we are just going to loop through the list of headers that are already in the file, and strip out the quotes then reassign the new list as the headers.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("your_csv_here.csv")

new_headers = []

for header in data.columns: # data.columns is your list of headers
    header = header.strip('"') # Remove the quotes off each header
    new_headers.append(header) # Save the new strings without the quotes

data.columns = new_headers # Replace the old headers with the new list
```

This cannot be done during the `file.to_csv("your_csv_here.csv")` function.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to accomplish this while writing the file data.to_csv. I tried using import csv and trying quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL but then the headers have the quotes and I'm trying to have all data but the headers have quotes, maybe write the file without headers and then add them back without quotes?

Comment: @JJordan I could be wrong, but I don't believe that this can happen in the `data.to_csv("path")` function. Is there any reason you cannot do it in the code while you are manipulating the data?

Comment: I'm finding that out, I think I will just write the file without headers and then just add them back in without the quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
headers = ["WD_Code", "_Supplier_Number", "Date_Of_Snapshot", "Time_Of_Snapshot"
"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"]
headers_no_quotes = []
for header in headers:
  headers_no_quotes.append(header.strip('\"'))
```

Comment: Ideally I'd like to accomplish this while writing the file data.to_csv. I tried using import csv and trying quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL but then the headers have the quotes and I'm trying to have all data but the headers have quotes, maybe write the file without headers and then add them back without quotes?